# Add class dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add the class last dynamically to every second row with jQuery as below

```
 <div class= "news-row">
    <article class="news-container fixed-page">  blah blah</article>
    <article class="news-container fixed-page">  blah blah2</article>
    </div>
```

Below is the jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('article.news-container :nth-child(2n)').addClass('last');
    });
</script>
```

This does not add the class.  Any help will be appreciated.
I want the every second article element to have "last" appended.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the selector? You have an `$` object for `article.news-container :nth-child(2n)`. Check what does it resolve to using `console.log`.

Comment: Use `:even` instead of `nth-child`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do not give space after selecting element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('article.news-container:nth-child(2n)').addClass('last');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yakc5yt/)

Comment: thanks for fixing my code your solution is the closest to my original attempt and so will give you the tick

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector...

```
$('article.news-container:even').addClass('last');
```

Comment: thanks your solution works as well as @Ashoks recommendation using the nth and odd selector which is faster?

Comment: [nth-child](http://jsperf.com/even-vs-nth-child-2n) is *much* faster. But it really shouldn't be much of a concern. Use whichever one makes the most sense to you.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Can you provide a reference / tests? I tend to use the most explicit operator simply for maintainability but if there's a clear performance benefit, `2n` is passably self-explanatory.

Comment: @Diin No worries... Pick whichever suits you best, that's what this site is all about! Anyway, glad to help and see you around.

Comment: @Basic: I put a link in my first comment. It's much faster, but you should know there's *no reason* to worry about speed in this case. I assume you're not going to be doing this a lot of times in a loop, and the speed difference is so small for a single usage that it'd be impossible to notice.

Answer (score 1):

An `article` node isn't a child of itself, so that selector won't work. Start with the parent instead (whose children are the `<article>` nodes):

```
$('.news-row :nth-child(2n)').addClass('last');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69hwq8tq/)

Comment: there are two other elements  inheriting the parent  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting a double quote on the first line, also do not add space before selector (:nth-child)

CodePen link below

http://codepen.io/kkirsche/pen/Hkutd

HTML:

```
 <div class="news-row">
     <article class="news-container fixed-page">  blah blah</article>
     <article class="news-container fixed-page">  blah blah2</article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.last {
    color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$('article.news-container:nth-child(2n)').addClass('last');
```